# C++ goto (rather than continue) syntactic oddity

Tags: c++, goto

I have the following code:

```
do
{
    doStuffP1();
    if (test)
    {    goto skip_increment;
    }
    dostuffP2();

    skip_increment:
    // 1;  // Only works if I remove the comment at line start.
} while (loop);
```

Which doesn't compile (VC++ 2010) with this error:

```
file_system_helpers.cpp(109) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

If I change it to:

```
skip_increment:

1;
```

It compiles (and works).

Is this really a limitation of C++ syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the "1;" was supposed to be missing from your first code snippet?

Look at this grammar here: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html

This defines labels only as a "labeled-statement". That is, a block body can contain `label: <statement>` anywhere in its sequence of contents, but the statement after the label is not optional. So this would make `skip_increment: }` invalid.

(And, OK, you're using C++ and not C; but I doubt if making allowances for extra uses of goto was something anyone cared much about while defining the C++ language.)

Comment: I recognize that `goto` is almost universally frowned upon, but I don't see a superior way to `continue` an outer loop from an inner loop.  The only ways I can think of involve an extra variable (a `bool` to store whether the outer loop should `continue` or not).

Comment: I would contend that using an extra `bool` would be better than a `goto`, but I'm pretty inexperienced as a programmer. I just don't believe that `goto` itself would be a safe statement to use, and the extra variable isn't going to cost that much, is it? But that's my 2c. ^^'

Comment: Extract the bit of code into a function and use an early return.

Comment: So it's use an extra variable, incur a stack wind/unwind/mark the function as `inline` and hope the compiler does so, or just use a `goto`.  Is the dogmatic hatred of `goto` so strong that I should incur a possible performance penalty (albeit small in this case) to avoid jumping two lines out of a loop?  I mean how is that any less clear than just `break` or `continue`?

Comment: it can [cause velociraptors to attack](http://xkcd.com/292/). Some people dislike `break` and particularly `continue` almost as much as `goto`. Other languages allow loops to be labelled so you can exit multiple levels at once. I personally would be pragmatic and use it if it works best. (I actually found the if/for/if on one line more disturbing than the goto, not least because I had to scroll to see it all)

Comment: One of my favourite features of PHP is the numbered `break` and `continue` statements, which allow you to break out of an arbitrary number of structures.  As for the `if`/`for`/`if` on one line, as I commented above -- before they were all deleted -- I work an an extremely large (2560x1600) monitor, so making statements wide rather than starting new lines mitigates the problem of scrolling to review/find code.  This is also a personal project so there's no style guide I necessarily must follow.

Comment: I prefer Perl's ability to label loops, makes for a natural `next OUTER_THING` statement to process... the next "outer thing"